# Documentdb performance when using pagination

Tags: azure, pagination, azure-cosmosdb

I have a working code on pagination which works great with azure search and sql, but when using it on documentdb it takes up to 60 seconds to load.

We beleive it's a latency issue, but I can't find a workaround to fasten it up,

any documentation, or ideas on where to start looking?

```
    public PagedList(IQueryable<T> superset, int pageNumber, int pageSize, string sortExpression = null)
    {
        if (pageNumber < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("pageNumber", pageNumber, "PageNumber cannot be below 1.");
        if (pageSize < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("pageSize", pageSize, "PageSize cannot be less than 1.");


        // set source to blank list if superset is null to prevent exceptions
        TotalItemCount = superset == null ? 0 : superset.Count();
        if (superset != null && TotalItemCount > 0)
        {
            Subset.AddRange(pageNumber == 1
                ? superset.Skip(0).Take(pageSize).ToList()
                : superset.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList()
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the LINQ provider for DocumentDB translates .Take() into a "TOP" SQL clause under certain circumstances, DocumentDB has no equivalent for Skip. So, I'm a little surprised it works at all but I suspect that the provider is rerunning the query from scratch to simulate Skip. In the comments [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-paging-support-with-top-and-more-query-improvements/) is a discussion led by a DocumentDB product manager on why they chose not to implement SKIP. tl;dr; It doesn't scale for NoSQL databases. I can confirm this with MongoDB (which does have a skip functionality). Later pages simply scan and throw away earlier documents. The later in the list you go, the slower it gets. I suspect that the LINQ implementation is doing something similar except client-side.

DocumentDB does have a mechanism for getting documents in chunks but it works a bit differently than SKIP. It uses a continuation token. You can even set a maxPageSize, however there is no guarantee that you'll get that number back.

I recommend that you implement a client-side cache of your own and use a fairly large maxPageSize. Let's say each page in your UI is 10 rows and your cache currently has 27 rows in it. If the user selects page 1 or page 2, you have enough rows to render the result from the data already cached. If the user select page 7, then you know that you need at least 70 rows in your cache. Use the last continuation token to get more until you have at least 70 rows in your cache and then render rows 61-70. On the plus side, continuation tokens are long lived so you can use them later based upon user input.

Comment: Thanks Larry, we are thinking on a migration to cassandra or couchdatabase, we are expecting over a million request per day on the ecommerce, do you have any favourite on the subject? (specially for orders and carts)

Comment: I'm a huge fan of PaaS offerings. Having built solutions with Cassandra, Couch (pre-Couchbase) and MongoDB, I find the ops burden of all of them to be too high (especially MongoDB). So, my current favorite is DocumentDB. I particularly like the ability to write ACID transactions in JavaScript. There are good no-ops alternatives on AWS and Google, and I would use those if the organization that I was working with had a preference, but none that just fit my mental model better than DocumentDB and I would miss it.

Comment: Thanks for your insights, we tried tokenization but it stucks our apis, I read they are updating json filters but we can-t wait for that, I was checking orientdb to see if it will perform better

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "updating json filters". That sounds interesting. Not familiar with OrientDB, but a lot of .NET folks choose RavenDB, which I also have no first-hand knowledge of.